# CSS: Fluid layout that expands into collapsable navbar

Tags: css, html, layout, fluid-layout

I have a layout designed in CSS that uses jQuery to expand and collapse the navbar. When collapsed, there is a lot of free space where the navbar used to be; ideally I'd like the content  to expand into it.

I have drawn a diagram:

[image: Diagram showing layout before and after collapsing of navbar]

I am currently achieving this using:

```
<div>
  <div id="navbar">
    Navbar content here
  </div>

  <div id="right-side-container">
    <div id="header">
      Header content here
    </div>
    <div id="data">
      Data here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

..where the "data" div has its width dynamically set by Javascript when the navbar is expanded / collapsed. How would I achieve this, other than by using `position: absolute`? I want to avoid `absolute` because it causes overlapping and general bad flow with the rest of the design. I think my `<div>`s are set up incorrectly.

Comment: if you use "float", you just need to change your property data. Example when your nav is expanded : #data {width:80%;margin:auto}. If you nav isn't expand : width:40% margin-left : ??px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    float: left;
}

#navbar.expd {
    height: 200px;
}

#header {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

#data {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#navbar').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expd');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5FCeV/